# Modifying MongoDB to allow cross origin requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, http-headers, cors

I am relatively new to MongoDB so I am still getting used to it.

Currently I am trying to post a json object to mongo from the client side using the code below in javascript.

```
var addUserButton = document.getElementById('add-user');
var userNameInput = document.getElementById('name');

addUserButton.onclick = function() {
    var newUser = new Object();
    newUser.name = userNameInput.value;
    var newUserJson = { 'name': newUser.name};
    $.post('127.0.0.1:27017/test', newUserJson);
};
```

When ever I run this code though I get  error stating:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load %3127.0.0.1:27017/test. Cross origin
>   requests are only supported for protocol schemes... etc

I read up on this and was wondering if adding the following CORS handler to mongoDB would fix this. If it is correct, how would I go about adding this to MongoDB? I could not find documentation on how to add this CORS handler to mongo

```
function handleCors(req, res, callback) {

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization');

    // CORS OPTIONS request, simply return 200
    if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.end();
        callback.onOptions();
        return;
    }

    callback.onContinue();
};
```

Comment: I've never tried communication directly with mongo.  I have, however, used express as an intermediary.  You can use node to query your DB, manipulate / stringify the results, and then send back the response.

Comment: Giving clients direct access to a database (especially write access) is rarely a good idea. You should implement a webservice in node.js accessing the database and then consume that webservice from the browser client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your work by concept is having issue.

1. Your post method is directly hitting to TCP Protocol here, which should not be.
2. You should call some http request based on some Rest API which is to be in Server.
3. At server routing, you should handle the CORS (http request) and then the db layer methods should get the data for Update/Select etc.

By the way, for Server Routing you can use high level node framework like [expressjs](http://expressjs.com/starter/basic-routing.html).

If you want a complete example for this, you may go through want to look through [this example](https://github.com/piyasde/express4mongoangular) and
the explanation can be found in at [Single Page Application with Angular.js, Node.js and MongoDB - phloxblog](http://www.phloxblog.in/single-page-application-angular-js-node-js-mongodb-mongojs-module-updated-express-4-part-1/).